# pgadmin 4 v 1.5.2 not starting in windows 8.1

Tags: pgadmin-4

I had installed pgadmin 4 - v1.5.2 on system with Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64bit Os. When I start pgadmin it's stuck with message - "Loading pgAdmin4 v1.5...". To troubleshoot I had made below changes to config_local.py.

1. Disable upgrade
2. Enable debug mode.
3. Set SERVER_MODE = False

Please find the last few lines of the logs and attached screenshot.

[image]

> 2017-06-21 14:44:24,789: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017
>   14:44:24] "GET /browser/server/static/js/variable.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   2017-06-21 14:44:25,585: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017
>   14:44:25] "GET /preferences/preferences/browser/show_node_schema
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 - 2017-06-21 14:44:26,296: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - -
>   [21/Jun/2017 14:44:26] "GET
>   /preferences/preferences/browser/show_node_sequence HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   2017-06-21 14:44:27,015: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017
>   14:44:27] "GET /preferences/preferences/browser/show_node_view
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 - 2017-06-21 14:44:27,737: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - -
>   [21/Jun/2017 14:44:27] "GET
>   /preferences/preferences/browser/show_node_mview HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   2017-06-21 14:44:27,908: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017
>   14:44:27] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 - 2017-06-21 14:44:28,573:
>   INFO  werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017 14:44:28] "GET
>   /preferences/preferences/browser/show_node_role HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   2017-06-21 14:44:28,710: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017
>   14:44:28] "GET /dashboard/static/img/welcome_logo.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>   2017-06-21 14:46:38,763: INFO werkzeug:   127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jun/2017
>   14:46:38] "POST /misc/ping HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I am not able to proceed with troubleshooting after this as I am not able to find any pointers. Please share inputs to fix this issue.

Comment: Please check my answer in this thread : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152779/launch-postgresql-gui)

Comment: Still facing the same issue after upgrading to new version.

Comment: Did you uninstalled previous version completely? 
Also remove all the files from C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin