# Launch PostgreSQL GUI

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have installed PostgreSQL v9.6 on Windows 7 using my user (PC-Admin), the problem is when I start Pgadmin4.exe the application shows that it is starting then freeze without showing the GUI , taking the following notes into consideration:

- it is working fine for other users on the PC even if not in admin group.
- I tried to uninstall it , delete registry folders for local machine & local user and also delete the temp folder and Apps roaming , also the folder of the program in c:/ drive and then re-install it again and problem has not been solved.

I believe that something went wrong during first time installation for my user 
but I could not figure it out.

Please help me, what to do in order to clear my installation profile and then having the GUI launched after short while from starting the Pgadmin4.exe

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Solved and GUI started ! just by disconnecting PC from internet before opening the application.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin4 hosts desktop application on 127.0.0.1:(Random_Port) when started, So if you have proxy setup then upgrade to pgAdmin4 version1.6, It  has resolved the this proxy related issue. ([Link](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/2398))